# Autodesk Inventor C# API UserParameter.set_Units 'object does not contain a definition for "set_Units"'

Tags: c#, autodesk-inventor

I am using Autodesk.Inventor.Interop.DLL to work with Autodesk Inventor API. 'Embed Interop Types' option is set to `false`.

The goal is to loop through all user model parameters and update values from a provided JSON file and it does work but I am unable to update **units** due to this error: `object does not contain a definition for "set_Units"`.

obj.unit is `string`

[image]

Any ideas how to set the units of user parameter?

Comment: Using `dynamic` is always such a pain. Try replacing dynamic with normal type and see what methods does it have.

Comment: `Any ideas how to set the units of user parameter?` Try consulting the manual fort the interop DLL.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to convert dynamic value to string:

```
string unit = Convert.ToString(obj.unit);
user_param.set_Units(unit);
```